# Jenkins login for local installation

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to log into my local jenkins server. I am running the server as a .war via

`java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8080`

I have tried finding the initial password from `$JENKINS_HOME/secrets/initialAdminPassword`, but it is not located there. I followed the step in this post too https://intellipaat.com/community/26950/default-credentials-for-jenkins-after-installation-windows-10-jenkins-default-password.  Nor does the original password from when I first set up the server work. I've deleted the original .war file, downloaded another war, tried running the server, but I am still running into the same issue.

Comment: What OS and how are you running Jenkins? Do you know your ${JENKINS_HOME} value? If WIN, Could be `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins` or your `<user home>\.jenkins`. UNIX could be `/var/lib/jenkins` or `~/.jenkins`

Comment: I am using macOS I don't see anything in `/var/lib` for jenkins. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Not a Mac user, but from other answers, `/Users/my_user/.jenkins` or  `/Users/Shared/Jenkins` ? Thereare options to paas in  a value for `JENKINS_HOME`, which would give you a fresh install to that location.